# how Install plex medi server on 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, plex

I got a recurrent error

```
Setting up plexmediaserver (1.0.0.2261-a17e99e) ...
OK
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/plexmediaserver.service to /lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service.
Job for plexmediaserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status plexmediaserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then `systemctl status plexmediaserver.service` gives

```
● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service.d
           └─overide.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-07-20 17:49:09 HKT; 2min 36s ago
  Process: 5531 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/m

Jul 20 17:49:04 homeserver systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 20 17:49:04 homeserver systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 20 17:49:09 homeserver systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 20 17:49:09 homeserver systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
Jul 20 17:49:09 homeserver systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 20 17:49:09 homeserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
```

I already tried different way to purge the previous install, nothing works. For info, the route that lead me here :
- See on plex web app that there is an update available, connect by SSH to my server , wget the deb file, then dpkg-i => failure
- I then decide de finally do the ubuntu 16.04 upgrade.
- after upgrade, still not working for the upgrade
- tried de-install, then re-install, no luck, try again with purge, still no luck.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614232/upgraded-to-15-04-and-plex-media-server-doesnt-work ?

Comment: create dir and chmod, no problem, then for the 2 following commands, it gives respectively `Failed to reset failed state of unit plexmediaserver.service: Unit plexmediaserver.service is not loaded.` and `Failed to start plexmediaserver.service: Unit plexmediaserver.service not found.`

Comment: scratch that, it was purged... I reinstalled it, got same error, while installing, then ran the code, first one ran properly (no output), the last line give me again `Job for plexmediaserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status plexmediaserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it ended up being a permission issue. so a

```
sudo chmod 0777 -R /var/lib/plexmediaserver
sudo chown plex:plex -R /var/lib/plexmediaserver
sudo service plexmediaserver restart
```

solved the issue

It appears as well that the `sudo apt-get remove --purge plexmediaserver` does not clean all things.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your own post as the answer :)

Comment: yes, needs to wait 2 days to do so :)